# Error in date conversion

Tags: c#, sql

I get this error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."
My code is below.

```
string[] closedate = lbldate_end.Text.Split(' ');
string txtdate = closedate[0];
string txttime = closedate[1];
```

Am getting date from SQL database in a label.
But i get it as 15-05-2014 00:00:00
so am splitting it. and then updating in database.but error is thrown.

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string

Please someone help me

Comment: Show the line that throws exception. What is the types of your columns? Why don't you keep this as a `DateTime` (parsing it) in your database? Keeping date and times as a string not a good idea.

Comment: PLease show the code where you actually do the conversion.

Comment: Why are you getting the date as a string in the first place? Fetch it as a `DateTime`. Avoid string conversions where you can.

Comment: My column is in date format

Comment: Is the  lbldate_end nullable?

Comment: Am retrieving as lbldate_end.Text = myReader["CLOSE_DATE"].ToString(); Please correct me to retrieve in date format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [SqlReader.GetDateTime function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdatetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in order to retrieve a date time column.

You can then use the [DateTime.ToString function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with custom formatting to fetch the date and the time in the desired format:

```
// assuming the column CLOSE_DATE is at position 5 = the fifth column from the table
var timestamp = myReader.GetDateTime(5);
Console.WriteLine(timestamp.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")); // date only
Console.WriteLine(timestamp.ToString("HH:mm:ss")); // time only
```

or

```
var timestamp = (DateTime)myReader["CLOSE_DATE"];
Console.WriteLine(timestamp.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
Console.WriteLine(timestamp.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
```

Assuming the field contains today and some time, then the output would be something like:

```
2014-05-15
13:18:31
```

Another possible solution could be found in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619216/reading-a-date-using-datareader).

Comment: it throws me error **Error The best overloaded method match for 'string.ToString(System.IFormatProvider)' has some invalid arguments**

Comment: If you are still using the `myReader["CLOSE_DATE"].ToString();` then remove the `.ToString()` in order to fetch the result as DateTime object and not as string and try again. Applying date formats on string is not possible.

Comment: Glad that the answer helped.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use

```
end.Text = (myReader["CLOSE_DATE"] as DateTime).ToString();
```

instead of your

```
end.Text = myReader["CLOSE_DATE"].ToString();
```