# Removing time part from a string c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to remove the time zone from a string.

The string looks like below.

> 2/05/2018 6:54:00 AM

This data has been retrieved from a local database.

Code Part:

```
 string datCommisioned = (rdr.GetValue(4).ToString());
 string dateonly = datCommisioned.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

When I tried to execute the above coding it's getting an error,

> cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IFormatProvider'

Any idea how to catch the date part excluding the time? Thanks!

Edit: This is probably not a duplicate question as I refer the other questions before posting. The context of this question is different because the string I'm extracting is not recognised as a valid DateTime (Manually entered by users) thus DateTime class cannot be used.

Comment: `datCommisioned` is string And You are trying to convert it to String again. String.ToString() accepts IFormatProvider.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading a date using DataReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619216/reading-a-date-using-datareader)

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619216/reading-a-date-using-datareader

Answer (score 2):

```
//Assuming value at index 4 is a DateTime.
string datCommisioned = rdr.GetDateTime(4).ToString(@"dd/MM/yyyy");
```

It's good practice to use the more specific and strongly typed methods with a DataReader.  Helps identify bugs faster.

Comment: why the '@' sign?

Comment: @pm100 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311988/what-is-the-difference-between-a-regular-string-and-a-verbatim-string

Comment: @pm100 to avoid escapes ('\') should they be added.  Habit of mine but is not necessary in the example.  Out of instinct I avoid escapes in format strings.

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches

1. Use `DateTime` object.

   ```
   DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse(datCommissioned);
   string dateonly = dateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
   ```
2. Split on whitespace

   ```
   var split = datCommissioned.Split(' ');
   string dateonly = split[0];
   ```

Comment: I wouldn't suggest a parse when you can get the DateTime directly from the DataReader

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto nowhere does it state that he is using a `DataReader`, although I see from the abbreviation why that is being assumed.

Comment: Yeah as Camilo mentioned I'm using a data reader object to read the data from a local database. This data has been inserted manually by users. There's an exception when I use DateTime class.

System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.' 

I recon the reason for this issue is because data was entered manually by users. @Tim

Comment: @mattdaemon lots of ways around that. Put a `try` around the `Parse`, or somehow ensure the data is correct before parsing. If it is saved/retrieved as a string, the other answer here won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change it to be this.

```
var datCommisioned = DateTime.parse(rdr.GetValue(4)).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

You are currently converting it to a string then trying to ToString() the String, when you just need to toString() the date from the reader.

Comment: How do you know the `GetValue` returns a `DateTime`?

Comment: Yeah just realized I don't. Need to edit it to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

Just another approach here; You can utilize DateTime.Parse() or perhaps a safer alternative, DateTime.TryParse(), to convert the string to a DateTime object. Then, use the Date property of the DateTime object to basically set the time to midnight, ie. 00:00:00. Depending on what you’re using the date for, having the DateTime object instead of a string could be helpful. You can then call ToString(“d”) or use another formatter to give you the date only portion in the desired format.

```
if (TryParse(datCommissioned, out DateTime commissionedDate))
{
       commisionedDate = commisionedDate.Date;
       string commissionedDateText = commissionedDate.ToString(“dd/MM/yyyy”);
}
```